# How do I verify a Google idToken in PHP?

Tags: php, phpseclib, google-identity

I have been working on this for far too long.  I am looking for a working example as of September 2016 for verifying a Google idToken such as

```
eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjZjNzgxOTQyZDg0OWJhMmVjZGE4Y2VkYjcyZDM0MzU3ZmM5NWIzMjcifQ.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.btukbBvhek6w14CrBVTGs8X9_IXIHZKpV1NzJ3OgbGUfmoRMirNGzZiFAgrR7COTeDJTamxRzojxxmXx6EEkQqNQcbyN8dO0PTuNt9pujQjLbFw_HBhIFJQaJSR3-tYPN-UtHGQ5JAAySsvCPapXbxyiKzTyvGYRSU65LmyNuiGxe6RQe1zHjq2ABJ4IPRqKPuFupnGRPWYyBSTPU7XQvtfhgyqA0BWZUfmCIFyDxQhvMaXNLTs01gnGVhcUDWZLi9vuUiKUlz3-aSSbwdfCMAljhBHnjpYO6341k5-qmgKkWawv8DX_nMEzntsCMCr664rP4wFEbsRB5ledM9Pc9Q
```

Using Google's recommended way and pulling "accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration" for the jwks_uri  and pulling that "www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs", yielding a relevant entry for

```
{
   "kty": "RSA",
   "alg": "RS256",
   "use": "sig",
   "kid": "6c781942d849ba2ecda8cedb72d34357fc95b327",
   "n": "s1dt5wFFaYl-Bt7Yb7QgWEatLJfxwWDhbd5yvm2Z4d1PRgNVQa9kwOArQNoOJ-b-oZnXLVFsVASUXEAumGf1ip5TVCQmMBKqlchSDNuoZfoWdpCCX7jx4gNuS43pS6VqV3QDjWnoXRTHaUi5pZEbpAmWpOeG_CfmewNVwBXPFx8-mtvEdtxIrspX4ayXTViR4vHc7MhQhUxllFbocxMjJysDQuZV9wN3MI0lVtQdf52SKJwF3lhvWA9-WAEZ1q8wq-I93Sfte95RaFjDqCH--Sh-8DjhK4OvgItcEGd5QRHjdLvrayPwaDQbpMRN2n3BkVWIxKJubtRiSeWbawCklQ",
   "e": "AQAB"
  }
```

Verification happens if I pass the token to https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=TOKEN, but this is not a real answer, since they don't change that often but doing an extra web call every time is just asking for trouble.

So can someone point me to a working example?  I've tried phpseclib, but it never verifies.  I've probably looked for about 40 hours at this point, and I'm at my wits' end.

Any help is appreciated.

My relevant code:

```
$modulus = "";
$exponent = "";
$token = $_POST['token'];
$pieces = explode(".", $token);
$header = json_decode(base64_decode(str_replace(['-','_'], ['+','/'], $pieces[0])), true);
$alg = $header['alg'];
$kid = $header['kid'];
$payload = base64_decode(str_replace(['-','_'], ['+','/'], $pieces[1]));
$signature = str_replace(['-','_'], ['+','/'], $pieces[2]);
//$signature = base64_decode(str_replace(['-','_'], ['+','/'], $pieces[2]));

if (testGoogleList($alg, $kid, $modulus, $exponent))
{

    echo "Found in list:  kid=".$kid."\n";
    echo "n: (base64URL)".$modulus."\n";
    echo "e: (base64URL)".$exponent."\n";
    $modulus = str_replace(['-','_'], ['+','/'], $modulus);
    $exponent = str_replace(['-','_'], ['+','/'], $exponent);
    echo "n: (base64)".$modulus."\n";
    echo "e: (base64)".$exponent."\n";
    $rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
    $rsa->setHash("sha256"); 
    $rsa->setSignatureMode(CRYPT_RSA_SIGNATURE_PKCS1); 
    $modulus = new Math_BigInteger($modulus, 256);
    $exponent = new Math_BigInteger($exponent, 256);
    echo "n: (BigInteger)".$modulus."\n";
    echo "e: (BigInteger)".$exponent."\n";
    $rsa->loadKey(array('n' => $modulus, 'e' => $exponent));
    $rsa->setPublicKey();
    $pubKey = $rsa->getPublicKey();
    echo "Public Key from phpseclib\n".$pubKey."\n";
    echo "--First openSSL error check--\n";
    while ($msg = openssl_error_string())
        echo $msg . "<br />\n";
    echo "--After First Error Check, before Verify--\n";
    $res = $rsa->verify($pieces[0].".".$pieces[1], $signature); 
    while ($msg = openssl_error_string())
        echo $msg . "<br />\n";
    echo "--Verify result: ".var_export($res, true)."--\n";
}
```

Output

```
Found in list:  kid=6c781942d849ba2ecda8cedb72d34357fc95b327
n: (base64URL)s1dt5wFFaYl-Bt7Yb7QgWEatLJfxwWDhbd5yvm2Z4d1PRgNVQa9kwOArQNoOJ-b-oZnXLVFsVASUXEAumGf1ip5TVCQmMBKqlchSDNuoZfoWdpCCX7jx4gNuS43pS6VqV3QDjWnoXRTHaUi5pZEbpAmWpOeG_CfmewNVwBXPFx8-mtvEdtxIrspX4ayXTViR4vHc7MhQhUxllFbocxMjJysDQuZV9wN3MI0lVtQdf52SKJwF3lhvWA9-WAEZ1q8wq-I93Sfte95RaFjDqCH--Sh-8DjhK4OvgItcEGd5QRHjdLvrayPwaDQbpMRN2n3BkVWIxKJubtRiSeWbawCklQ
e: (base64URL)AQAB
n: (base64)s1dt5wFFaYl+Bt7Yb7QgWEatLJfxwWDhbd5yvm2Z4d1PRgNVQa9kwOArQNoOJ+b+oZnXLVFsVASUXEAumGf1ip5TVCQmMBKqlchSDNuoZfoWdpCCX7jx4gNuS43pS6VqV3QDjWnoXRTHaUi5pZEbpAmWpOeG/CfmewNVwBXPFx8+mtvEdtxIrspX4ayXTViR4vHc7MhQhUxllFbocxMjJysDQuZV9wN3MI0lVtQdf52SKJwF3lhvWA9+WAEZ1q8wq+I93Sfte95RaFjDqCH++Sh+8DjhK4OvgItcEGd5QRHjdLvrayPwaDQbpMRN2n3BkVWIxKJubtRiSeWbawCklQ
e: (base64)AQAB
n: (BigInteger)18674717054764783973087488855176842456138281065703345249166514684640666364313492818979675328236363014396820758462507776710767978395332237045824933690552916871072924852353561300648679961653291310130667565640227949181785672954620248276915721938277908962537175894062430220752771265500386404609948390377043762106166027544443459977210114747088393335234720657330424186435226141073425445733987857419933850994487913462193466159335385639996611717486282518255208499657362420183528330692236194252505592468150318350852955051377118157817611947817677975817359347998935961426571802421142861030565807099600656362069178972477827638867161671399657071319083914500667014214521757304661303525496653078786180348831678824969667950119891369610525474165187687495455755684504105433077872587114630537058768184460798470456362909589578101896361255070801
e: (BigInteger)1095844162
Public Key from phpseclib
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBeDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAWUAMIIBYAKCAVZzMWR0NXdGRmFZbCtCdDdZ
YjdRZ1dFYXRMSmZ4d1dEaGJkNXl2bTJaNGQxUFJnTlZRYTlrd09BclFOb09KK2Ir
b1puWExWRnNWQVNVWEVBdW1HZjFpcDVUVkNRbU1CS3FsY2hTRE51b1pmb1dkcEND
WDdqeDRnTnVTNDNwUzZWcVYzUURqV25vWFJUSGFVaTVwWkVicEFtV3BPZUcvQ2Zt
ZXdOVndCWFBGeDgrbXR2RWR0eElyc3BYNGF5WFRWaVI0dkhjN01oUWhVeGxsRmJv
Y3hNakp5c0RRdVpWOXdOM01JMGxWdFFkZjUyU0tKd0YzbGh2V0E5K1dBRVoxcTh3
cStJOTNTZnRlOTVSYUZqRHFDSCsrU2grOERqaEs0T3ZnSXRjRUdkNVFSSGpkTHZy
YXlQd2FEUWJwTVJOMm4zQmtWV0l4S0p1YnRSaVNlV2Jhd0NrbFECBEFRQUI=
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
--First openSSL error check--
--After First Error Check, before Verify--
error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line

--Verify result: false--
```

Comment: Could you post some sample ciphertext that the public key ought to be able to decrypt? Without that it's impossible to test the key. Also, could you maybe post a link to some documentation for Google Identity? I did a Google Search but what I found didn't talk about RSA..

Comment: "google-identity" was just the closest tag I could find for this.  A better but non-existent one would be "google-token" or "google-idtoken".  I will look for documentation.

Comment: The only documentation I'm finding is out of date (hence the question in the first place), but it should explain what I'm looking for.  (https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/CrossClientAuth), (http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/01/using-google-sign-in-with-your-server.html), and (http://www.riskcompletefailure.com/2013/11/client-server-authentication-with-id.html) all give pieces of what I'm looking for, but nothing usable for my PHP service currently.

Comment: Also, the part that SHOULD be decrypted is in that token.  There are 3 pieces split by periods.  It's in the form of header "." payload "." signature.  So the signature should be good for (header "." payload) as I understand it, but that isn't even that clear to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're not base64-decoding anything relevant.

This worked for me (told me that the signature was valid):

```
<?php
include('Crypt/RSA.php');

$data = 'eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjZjNzgxOTQyZDg0OWJhMmVjZGE4Y2VkYjcyZDM0MzU3ZmM5NWIzMjcifQ.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';
$signature = 'btukbBvhek6w14CrBVTGs8X9_IXIHZKpV1NzJ3OgbGUfmoRMirNGzZiFAgrR7COTeDJTamxRzojxxmXx6EEkQqNQcbyN8dO0PTuNt9pujQjLbFw_HBhIFJQaJSR3-tYPN-UtHGQ5JAAySsvCPapXbxyiKzTyvGYRSU65LmyNuiGxe6RQe1zHjq2ABJ4IPRqKPuFupnGRPWYyBSTPU7XQvtfhgyqA0BWZUfmCIFyDxQhvMaXNLTs01gnGVhcUDWZLi9vuUiKUlz3-aSSbwdfCMAljhBHnjpYO6341k5-qmgKkWawv8DX_nMEzntsCMCr664rP4wFEbsRB5ledM9Pc9Q';
$signature = str_replace(['-','_'], ['+','/'], $signature);
$signature = base64_decode($signature);

$n = 's1dt5wFFaYl-Bt7Yb7QgWEatLJfxwWDhbd5yvm2Z4d1PRgNVQa9kwOArQNoOJ-b-oZnXLVFsVASUXEAumGf1ip5TVCQmMBKqlchSDNuoZfoWdpCCX7jx4gNuS43pS6VqV3QDjWnoXRTHaUi5pZEbpAmWpOeG_CfmewNVwBXPFx8-mtvEdtxIrspX4ayXTViR4vHc7MhQhUxllFbocxMjJysDQuZV9wN3MI0lVtQdf52SKJwF3lhvWA9-WAEZ1q8wq-I93Sfte95RaFjDqCH--Sh-8DjhK4OvgItcEGd5QRHjdLvrayPwaDQbpMRN2n3BkVWIxKJubtRiSeWbawCklQ';
$n = str_replace(['-','_'], ['+','/'], $n);
$n = base64_decode($n);

$e = 'AQAB';
$e = base64_decode($e);

$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
$rsa->loadKey([
    'n' => new Math_BigInteger($n, 256),
    'e' => new Math_BigInteger($e, 256)
]);

$rsa->setHash('sha256');
$rsa->setSignatureMode(CRYPT_RSA_SIGNATURE_PKCS1);

echo $rsa->verify($data, $signature) ?
    'valid' :
    'invalid';
```

Comment: OMG.  So I forgot to do a base64_decode on the mod and exp, even after I labelled them as such in my output.  Sigh.  I knew it would be something stupid.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

So for anyone coming here from search engines:

I was trying to use a Google ID Token to verify that my login credentials were:
Accurate
Not spoofed
Able to be checked by a back-end server
Computed using math so I don't have to query Google each time (adding latency and the if-anything-can-go-wrong-it-will effect)

I realize that most will certainly be able to read this code, but I wanted to type it up to explain what's happening for the next exasperated soul.

Your first part may vary, since I was coming from Android and it's fairly straight-forward from there.

My process was to ask for the token in Android.
(Only differences from examples and relevant pieces shown)

```
   GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
        .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.client_id))
        .requestEmail()
        .build();
```

Getting the token from the Activity Result (onActivityResult)

```
   GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
    String idToken = acct.getIdToken();
```

The token is composed of 3 pieces, separated by periods, in the form "$header.$info.$signature".  We will verify "$header.$info" using "$signature" to do so.

The $header contains information about the encryption, for example (after decoding):

```
{"alg":"RS256","kid":"6c781942d849ba2ecda8cedb72d34357fc95b327"}
```

So the algorithm used is "SHA-256, with RSA Encryption", and the Key ID in the keystore is 6c781942d849ba2ecda8cedb72d34357fc95b327.  We'll use this later.

Pass the whole token to my back-end server via HTTP

Then decode the token using the following code, taken straight from the accepted answer

```
include('Crypt/RSA.php');  //path to phpseclib

$modulus = "";
$exponent = "";
$token = $_POST['token'];
$pieces = explode(".", $token);

$data = $pieces[0].".".$pieces[1];
$signature = base64_decode(str_replace(['-','_'], ['+','/'], $pieces[2]));

$header = json_decode(base64_decode(str_replace(['-','_'], ['+','/'], $pieces[0])), true);
$alg = $header['alg'];
$kid = $header['kid'];

if (testGoogleList($alg, $kid, $modulus, $exponent))
{
    $modulus = base64_decode(str_replace(['-','_'], ['+','/'], $modulus));
    $exponent = base64_decode(str_replace(['-','_'], ['+','/'], $exponent));

    $rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
    $rsa->loadKey([
        'n' => new Math_BigInteger($modulus, 256),
        'e' => new Math_BigInteger($exponent, 256)
    ]);

    $rsa->setHash('sha256');
    $rsa->setSignatureMode(CRYPT_RSA_SIGNATURE_PKCS1);

    if ($rsa->verify($data, $signature))
    {
        echo "VALID!!!!";
    } else {
        echo "NOT VALID :'(";
    }
}
```

The reason we do `base64_decode(str_replace(['-','_'], ['+','/'], $VARIABLE))` is because these are presented in `base64URL` form, where the '+' is changed to a '-' and the '/' is changed to a '_'.  So we change it from base64URL > base64 > unencoded (plain) text.

What does this do?

- We take the token from $_POST (I called it $token).
- Then we split it into its parts.
- Remember we need to use the third part to decode the pair of the first two, separated by a period (".").  ("$signature" is the cryptographic signature for "$header.$info")
- Fully decode the signature, from base64URL to unencoded (plain) text.
  Since Google uses JSON to store the key information, json_decode the header and get the encryption type and key id.
- I wrapped it in a function, but my function `testGoogleList` basically works like this:

  1. So we pass in the algorithm and the key id.
  2. I test my local cache of keys to see if the key we need is already cached.
  3. If not, we continue here, otherwise skip ahead to step 4.

     - Then we hit the web and grab Google's open-id configuration page at (https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration) using get_file_contents() or a CURL method if you can't.  I had to use CURL with options "curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANYSAFE);" in my CURL method, since it wasn't trying HTTPS correctly.
     - That page is a JSON encoded text file, so json_decode it.
     - We them grab the "jwks_uri" key and grab that page like we did above.
     - This contains a set of keys Google is currently using for public key verification.  I json_decode and temporarily store these to an array.
     - Truncate your old cache and rewrite the set.  Don't forget to flock() in case of truly poor timing.
     - Make sure your key is in the new set.
  4. If we find the key in our cache, we extract the "n" (we'll call this the 'modulus') and "e" ('exponent') pieces from it and pass those back.
- Then we decode the modulus and exponent pieces from base64URL > base64 > unencrypted (plain) text.
- Create a new instance of class Crypt_RSA.
- Load the numbers you just decrypted into that class as a new key, with types of Math_BigInteger so we can do math on giant numbers. (the second argument is base, so base 256 is a byte, if we are working with BIG integers, use this)
- Set our hash and signature mode to match what we have from Google.
- Do the verify to ensure we have a valid key.

After this it's up to you what you do with it.

Thank you once again, neubert, for the help!